Cannot add new rows to postgres table and receive message Could not read block 2 in file "base/16385/16433": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
I copy and paste the new row in a table in postgres database, and recieve the following error
Could not read block 2 in file "base/16385/16433": read only 0 of 8192 bytes

The cause was a data corruption in the database table and I was able to fix by the follwing commands.
VACUUM FULL public."TableName"
